# wp_update_post based function works on existing posts, but not new posts

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, wp-update-post

I have a function that will update the title of the post based on an 'advanced custom field'.

It works on existing posts, but not when I create a new post. When I try and save the post and check the post listings, it isn't there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function my_post_title_updater( $post_id ) {

    if ( get_post_type() == 'equipment' ) {

        $my_post = array();
        $my_post['post_title'] = get_field( 'item_name', $post_id );

        wp_update_post( $my_post );

    }

}

// run after ACF saves the $_POST['fields'] data
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_post_title_updater', 20);
```

Comment: Could it be something to do with the post_id not existing on first save?

Comment: I've created a video of the problem. - [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzkWP_SBRjU](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzkWP_SBRjU)

Comment: The post ID is created before the see the blank post screen for the first time-- there is a kind of automatic auto-save that generates an empty post as soon as you get to the "new post" page..

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't adding the ID into the new array.

```
if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'equipment' ) {

    $my_post = array();
    $my_post['ID'] = $post_id;
    $my_post['post_title'] = get_field( 'name', $post_id );

    wp_update_post( $my_post );

}
```